# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS freezes after changing keyboard layout two times and black screen after pressing CAPSLOCK

Tags: updates, keyboard-layout, capslock

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS w/ 11 november 18 updates freezes after changing keyboard layout two times (<kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>) and black screen after pressing <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> two times. System can be shutdown only by pressing powerbutton.

I have faced this problem on Ubuntu 18.10 (non-LTS), Mint 19 Tara, Debian 9.6 two weeks ago, but then have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Razer Blade Stealth laptop and everything was fine before today's updates.

Comment: I am not sure whether you can uninstall the last update. But I know you can see what packages were updated: check this link to know which packages were updated in the last update: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/152733/how-can-i-remove-all-updates-installed-after-a-specific-date
You can also check this link too: https://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/debian-linux/ubuntu-linux-rollback-an-apt-get-upgrade/